# How can I get the selected value from my <select>

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I try to get the value from the select area using form and $_Post. I looked through plenty of older questions and am sure, I followed the instructions. still i get the error: Undefined array key "platz".

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <select  name="platz">
          <?php
            for ($i=0; $i < $saalinfo[2]; $i++) {
              echo "<option value='$i'> Reihe $i </option>";
            }
           ?>
        </select>


        <select class="" name="reihe">
          <?php
            for ($i=0; $i < $saalinfo[3]; $i++) {
              echo "<option value='$i'> Spalte $i </option>";
            }
           ?>
        </select>

        <?php echo "($_POST[platz])" ?>

        </form>
```

For clarification Saalinfo 2 and 3 contain integer so that there are different options to choose from based on the given values. Many Thanks in advance.

I also tried

```
<?php echo "($_POST['platz'])" ?>
```

Comment: Before form is sent `$_POST['xxx']` doesn't exist.

Comment: Try <?php echo $_POST['platz']; ?> Do you send the form?

Comment: The issue with your second attempt may be string concatenation. Similar to @Oleg's suggestion, have you tried `echo "(".$_POST['platz'].")";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads initially there will be no `POST` data so you get that error. Instead check that POST array is available first - like so perhaps:

```
<?php echo !empty( $_POST['platz'] ) ? $_POST['platz'] : ''; ?>
```